# File upload requests all return 400 status codes

Tags: javascript, express, file-upload, multipartform-data

I'm trying to get file uploading working with Express, but every `multipart/form-data` request I send gets a 400 bad request response with no error. Just an empty object. I'm currently using [busboy-body-parser](https://github.com/lennym/busboy-body-parser) for parsing multipart formdata requests, but I also tried [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload) and ran into the exact same issue.

Here are my request methods:

```js
get(endpoint) {
  return this.request('GET', endpoint, null);
}

post(endpoint, body) {
  return this.request('POST', endpoint, body);
}

postFile(endpoint, file) {
  return this.request('POST', endpoint, file, contentTypes.file);
}

async request(method, endpoint, body, contentType=contentTypes.json) {
  const { authToken } = this;
  const endpointUrl = this.getEndpointUrl(endpoint);
  const headers = new Headers();

  if(authToken) {
    headers.append(authTokenHeader, authToken);
  }
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json, application/xml, text/plain, text/html, *.*');
  headers.append('Content-Type', contentType);

  const response = await fetch(endpointUrl, {
    method: method,
    headers: headers,
    body: this._serializeRequestBody(body, contentType),
  });

  const result = await this._parseResponse(response);

  if(!response.ok) {
    if(response.status === 401) {
      this.revokeAuth();
    }
    throw result || new Error('Unknown error (no error in server response)');
  } else if(result && result.authToken) {
    this.setAuthToken(result.authToken);
  }

  return result;
}
```

Here is `_serializeRequestBody` and `_parseResponse`:

```js
_parseResponse(response) {
  const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type').split(';')[0];
  if(contentType === contentTypes.json) {
    return response.json();
  }
  return response.text();
}

_serializeRequestBody(body, contentType) {
  if(!body) return null;
  switch(contentType) {
    case contentTypes.json:
      return JSON.stringify(body);
    case contentTypes.file:
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', body);
      return formData;
  }
  return body;
}
```

And `contentTypes`:

```
const contentTypes = {
  json: 'application/json',
  file: 'multipart/form-data',
};
```

And my express middleware:

```
if(this._expressLoggingMiddleware) {
  app.use(this._expressLoggingMiddleware);
}

if(this.isNotProductionEnv && this.isNotTestEnv) {
  app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
}

// Adds `res.success` and `res.fail` utility methods.
app.use(require('./utils/envelopeMiddleware')());

// Allow cross-origin requests if `config.cors` is `true`.
if(config.cors) app.use(require('cors')());

// Parse JSON and form request bodies.
app.use(busboyBodyParser()); // parses multipart form data (used for file uploads)
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Lookup users by the JWT in their request header.
app.use(passportJWTMiddleware(passport, this.jwtSecret, jwtPayload =>
  this.lookupUserfromAuthToken(jwtPayload).catch((error) => {
    log.warn('Error while looking up user from JWT:', error);
    return null;
  })
));

// Serve files from `config.publicDir`.
if(config.publicDir) {
  log.debug(`Hosting static files in "${config.publicDir}"`);
  app.use(express.static(config.publicDir));
}
```

Here is the request info in Chrome's dev tools

[image: Chrome dev tools request information]

And the request payload:

[image: Chrome dev tools request payload]

And the response:

[image: Chrome dev tools response]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer ended up being: don't manually set the `Content-Type` header to `multipart/form-data` because if you let the browser do it for you, it will also tack on the required `boundary` value to the content type.

So in order to fix my code, I just have to only set the `Content-Type` header explicitly when sending JSON:

```
if(contentType === contentTypes.json) headers.append('Content-Type', contentType);
```